# Black screen when trying to boot to Ubuntu and Mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, system-installation

I am trying to install Linux on my new build. I have fired it up and I can see all of my hardware correctly in the bios. I have tried installing Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, and Mint. Each time, I start booting from the USB and get to the list of options like "Try or Install Ubuntu", "Run Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)", etc. I tried normal and safe graphics for each of the distros that I mentioned. Each time I click run, from here it is nothing but a black screen no matter how long I wait.  Next I tried Mint Edge 21.3 and Ubuntu 23.10 to ensure that I had a newer kernel, but the results were the same.

- I did open up the GRUB cli on one of the Ubuntu distro menus, that seemed to be working but it had the same result when I tired to boot from USB.
- I tried plugging the monitor into the mobo instead of the graphics card in case it was a driver issue causing the black screen.
- Accessories seem to lose power after I try to boot as my keyboard and mouse lose their lighting.

My build parts in case they are relevant:

- CPU: AMD RYZEN 7 7700X
- Mobo: MSI PRO B650-P WIFI ATX
- Hard drive: NVME M2 drive
- Graphics Card: Radeon RX7800XT (but I am plugging the monitor directly into the mother board.)

Any advice on how to get my PC to boot from the Linux USB would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the system configured to boot using UEFI or traditional CSM BIOS?